# Disposable HtmlString Extension for Authorization purposes

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, extension-methods, asp.net-authorization

I'm intending to create an extension for MVC that looks like this:

```
public static class DivExtension
{

    public static MvcHtmlElement BeginDiv(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {

        return new MvcDiv(helper.ViewContext).BeginDiv("","");
    } 
    public static MvcHtmlElement BeginDiv(this HtmlHelper helper, string id)
    {

        return new MvcDiv(helper.ViewContext).BeginDiv(id,"");
    } 
}
```

In Razor I could use it like this:

```
@{using(Html.BeginDiv())
  {
        <text>
              This should appear inside a div <input type="text" value="oi" />
        </text>
   }
}
```

Which would generate the following HTML output:

```
 <div>
   This should appear inside a div <input type="text" value="oi" />
 </div>
```

But imagine that instead of just creating a **div**, my code would receive a string representing roles and, if the logged in user does not belong to the specified Roles, the HTML within this extension should be suppressed:

```
public static class HtmlAuthSuppressor
{

    public static MvcHtmlElement AuthHTML(this HtmlHelper helper, string roles)
    { 
        //some code that would allow suppression
    }  
}
```

and If I use like this:

```
<b>Do you see something below?</b>
@{using(Html.AuthHTML("Role_Super_User"))
  {
        <text>
              Congratz!!! You can see this, u are super, indeed. <input type="text" value="oi" />
        </text>
   }
}
```

The final HTML output, in case the user does not belong to the specified role, would be:

```
<b>Do you see something below?</b>
```

Is that possible?

**UPDATE:**
I know I could generate an HTML like this:

```
   <b>Do you see something below?</b> 
     <!--   
              Congratz!!! You can see this, u are super, indeed. <input type="text" value="oi" />
        --!>
```

But that would reveal something to the client that I wouldn't like to reveal, besides making the response unnecessarily heavier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build an extension for that.. just do this:

```
<b>Do you see something below?</b>

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Role_Super_User"))
    {
        <text>
              Congratz!!! You can see this, u are super, indeed. <input type="text" value="oi" />
        </text>
    }
```

Comment: I got it! Thanks! But what if I want to - as in the DIV example - to delegate the logic to the extension method? Would you recommend doing the following?
`@{using(var div = Html.BeginDiv())
    {

if(div.canBeDisplayed)
{
        <text>
              This should appear inside a div <input type="text" value="oi" />
        </text>
}
   }
}`

Comment: It depends. If you are wanting to show different content based on different roles, then yeah.. I don't see why you couldn't delegate that to the extension..especially if you are going to do something more complex than just: `User.IsInRole("RoleName")`. Is it you're having trouble implementing it or you just want to know others' opinions on this?

Comment: What I wanted more was to know if it was possible to render different content depending on the circumstances. But I think it's not possible to ignore the content in the `text` tags and render some different things in my disposable context (not necessarily for authentication purposes).